# spark-xml on jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run spark-xml on my jupyter notebook in order to read xml files using spark.

```
from os import environ
environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 pyspark-shell'
```

I found out that this is way to use it. But when I try to import `com.databricks.spark.xml._`, I get an error saying

> no module named "com"

Comment: spark-xml is primarily for use with Scala, not Python. See the [readme](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#pyspark-notes)

Comment: Python imports also don't have underscores, so why did you think copying the Scala code would work?

Comment: I provided a detailed answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951922/read-xml-using-pyspark-in-jupyter-notebook/67810200#67810200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are not able to load xml file as it is , using pyspark and databricks lib, this problem happens offen, well try to run this command from your teminal or from your notebook as a shell command :

```
 pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1
```

if it does not work you can try this work around, as you can read your file as a text then parse it.

```
#define your parser function: input is rdd: 
def parse_xml(rdd):
    """
    Read the xml string from rdd, parse and extract the elements,
    then return a list of list.
    """


    return results

#read the file as text at a RDD level
file_rdd = spark.read.text("/path/to/data/*.xml", wholetext=True).rdd
# parse xml tree, extract the records and transform to new RDD
records_rdd = file_rdd.flatMap(parse_xml)
# convert RDDs to DataFrame with the pre-defined schema
output_df = records_rdd.toDF(my_schema)
```

If the .toDf will not work import spark.implicit.

Comment: Hey, I am using the second way to parse the xml file. But this happens only on one partition and even after I convert the rdd to a dataframe and run my udfs on it, it is happening on 1 partition only. I would not like to manually control the partitions. is there a work around for this?